# What can be done to improve this answer?

Tags: discussion

@AmroKabeel posted an answer to this question:[What is the ethnicity of the Sabeans?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/59756/1401) . The answer was flagged as low quality and acting on behalf of the community I deleted the answer. AmroKabeel asked me to reverse that deletion; I feel that it is inappropriate for the moderator to overrule a community flag.

That said, AmroKabeel expressed a desire to participate in H:SE; normally I'd advise the user to raise the question in meta, but AmroKabeel doesn't have sufficient reputation.  In an effort to create a welcoming environment for new users, and to provide the opportunity for constructive feedback for new users I invite you to use the space below to suggest how the answer could be revised to more closely fulfill the community's vision for H:SE.

In order to facilitate constructive feedback, I've copied the answer below.

---

> There are two different types of “Sabeans”. The first is the Soba descended from Ham that are native to Sudan which the Persians later conquered and changed to Meroe. And there is the Saba of Yemen who is an Arab man that had 10 children; 4 of which went to Syria and 6 of which stayed in Yemen; and they all formed major tribes. I’ll call the first Sobas and the second Sabeans.
>
> Now, if you discard the spoonfed brainwash that the traditional institutions and academia teach you and embark on some researching using The Holy Quran, The Narrations of Prophet Muhammad (PPBUH), The Bible, some dictionaries, the internet/encyclopedia/history books, and just common sense you would realize that Ethiopia is the land of Canaan that later became the holy land of Israel-Judah. It is purely Divine Will to have it hidden from the masses, so it’s okay if you don’t buy it; but it is the truth. With that said, here are the answers to your questions:
>
> I want to know if the Sabean people truly existed (archaeological evidence)
>   Soba in Sudan - Look up Meroe Saba in Yemen - Too much left behind there. The Musnad and Zabur script are attributed to them, and a theory suggests that the Zabur script, which was developed by them as a cursive form of the Musnad script, was the foundation of the Syriac script; you can actually see it just by looking at the pictures. After the Mar’ib Dam collapsed many Sabeans migrated to Syria and mixed with the Assyrians there, and in due time they developed the Syriac script by mixing the Aramaic and the Zabur, and this script was fully functional by the first century AD. Many scholars claim the Peshitta Bible was the origin of scriptures because it was written in Syriac, and some linguists say the Arabic script was developed from the Syriac as well.
>
> Where are their descendants today?
>   Soba - In Africa & other places. Saba - In Yemen, Ethiopia, Syria, Iraq, & other places.
>
> Why does modern archaeology attribute a Semitic, Arabian and Yemeni origin to these people.
>   Naturally, historians are just a bit confused. Soba of Sudan - Descendants of Ham. Saba of Yemen - Descendants of Sam,
>
> Whether or not there is any evidence for their Ethiopian origin as Josephus Flavius suggests.
>   This is a tricky question... The Sabeans of Yemen would cross to Ethiopia frequently and indeed there are some of their writings left behind from the 8th century BC around Yeha temple and many historians have hypothesized about the reasons why. The best explanation I’ve found for this is in these two videos below. The whole YouTube channel is quite useful for your inquiry if you’d like to do further research, “Revisionists - official channel” www.revisionists.org .
>
> Biblical Archeology in Ethiopia - Intro part 1 https://youtu.be/fPFEiBKrBdE
>
> Biblical Archeology in Ethiopia - Intro part 2 https://youtu.be/srBWW50YlxA
>
> Now regarding your inquiry for The Queen of Sheba (Soba in Sudan and previously Meroe), ponder on the following verse of The Holy Quran. Her connection to Prophet Solomon (PPBUH) is that a Hoopoe bird was flying when he found the people of Soba in Sudan worshiping the sun and Solomon (PPBUH) invited them to monotheism and merged the two kingdoms by marrying Balqees The Queen of Sheba. The two kingdoms were Ethiopia and Egypt minor that is Sudan today, that could be what Josephus was talking about.
>
> “In Sheba’s homeland there used to be a wonder: two gardens [Metaphor for 2 Rivers], on the right, and on the left. “Eat of your Lord’s provision, and give thanks to Him.” A good land, and a forgiving Lord. But they turned away, so We sent against them a devastating flood; and We substituted their two gardens with two gardens of bitter fruits, thorny shrubs, and meager harvest. We thus penalized them for their ingratitude. Would We penalize any but the ungrateful? Between them and the towns We had blessed, We placed prominent towns, and We made the travel between them easy. “Travel between them by night and day, in safety.” But they said, “Our Lord, lengthen the distances of our journeys.” They wronged themselves; so We made them as tales [of history] and dispersed them in total dispersion. In this are lessons for every steadfast and appreciative person.” - (The Holy Quran, 34:15-19)
>
> The sister that commented above is on point. The ethnic Israelites originally have darker complexion and there are many clues for that in The Bible and Prophet Muhammad (PPBUH) said it bluntly in many of his narrations, he even said Jesus (PPBUH) had a brown complexion (Sahih al-Bukhari, 3438). The modern Jewish identity wasn’t created until after the Babylonian exile when Persian converts entered Judaism. Then the Palestinian Jewish homeland was created by the Hasmonean dynasty who if you look up there names can clearly tell we’re all Seleucid empire converts. This is all supported by historical facts as Palestine was just a bunch of villages before the Hasmoneans and didn’t even have a writing system, they have no archeological proof for the Kingdom of David being there. But anyway, that’s another story for another time. I’m just going to leave you with two more clues so you don’t think I’m crazy or something, one from The Bible and one from The Holy Quran.
>
> Do you agree that the lands of Syria and Palestine have the same produce? Geographically, and for someone who lives in the Middle East, I affirm you that they do. “Judah and Israel traded with you; they exchanged wheat from Minnith and confections, honey, olive oil, and balm for your wares. Damascus did business with you because of your many products and great wealth of goods. They offered wine from Helbon, wool from Zahar.” - (The Bible, Ezekiel 27:17-18). What’s Ethiopia most of famous for? Well, their Injara bread which is unique to their land in Minnith, their honey because it’s all highlands and mountains, their olives and figs, and their Shea butter. When God promised the land of Canaan to Abraham (PPBUH), He promised a land flowing with milk and honey, and He is the best of all to describe anything. If that land had been Palestine, shouldn’t he have said a land flowing with olive oil? God is referring to produce here, and milk is a produce of green lands that cattle eat while honey is a produce of highlands and a mountainous areas. The Holy Quran goes further to prove that Ethiopia is The Holy Land as God mentions “And a tree that springeth forth from Tûr-Sinai [The Mountainous Chain of Sinai] that groweth butter and relish for the eaters.” (23:20). Shea butter is native to Ethiopia and central Africa and it doesn’t grow anywhere else in the planet. As The Bible confirms, Israel and Judea traded balm, that is Shea butter, with Tyre. There are numerous proofs, but truth is precious and only for the diligent seekers.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** [The answer has now been re-posted](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/59767/40279), addressing most of the criticisms I initially lined out. However, it still lacks sources for any of the claims it is making. The only links are to two YouTube videos, with the intention that OP "do his own research", which again, misses the point of what sources are supposed to be used for. This still needs to be addressed before the answer can be thought of as high-quality.

Original answer below.

---

This is the bit that sticks out to me as problematic:

> Now, if you discard the spoonfed brainwash that the traditional institutions and academia teach you and embark on some researching using The Holy Quran, The Narrations of Prophet Muhammad (PPBUH), The Bible, some dictionaries, the internet/encyclopedia/history books, and just common sense you would realize that Ethiopia is the land of Canaan that later became the holy land of Israel-Judah. It is purely Divine Will to have it hidden from the masses, so it’s okay if you don’t buy it; but it is the truth.

There are three things wrong with this:

1. This entire section is, as far as I can tell, completely irrelevant to the question. I don't see how Ethiopia being the holy land of Canaan relates to whether the Sabeans came from there or not. Maybe there is a connection, but Amro needs to make it clearer. I think it got lost somewhere in the giant wall of text that constitutes the final three paragraphs.
2. Phrases like "the spoonfed brainwash that the traditional institutions and academia teach you" are an immediate red flag to me. They make you sound like a conspiracy theorist. (I also find it bizarre how Amro goes straight from trashing the "traditional institutions and academia" to suggesting the OP read some history books. Who does he think *writes* the history books? What does he think academia *use* to "brainwash" people?)
3. "If you... embark on some researching" is not something that belongs in a Stack Exchange answer. If you have evidence to back up what you're saying, *provide it*. The onus is on *you* to back up what you are saying, not on the OP to go check for themselves.

The final three paragraphs, as I mentioned, are quite lengthy and messy, and it's hard to tell how much of it is relevant to the original question. They could definitely do with being broken up or trimmed down.

Overall, however, this *is* an attempt to answer the question - it directly addresses all  four of OP's queries. It's just hard to tell because it gets sidetracked by issues that don't seem to be directly related.

Comment: Did you read through the whole, or/and the 'new' version? Meaning: That para is *far* from the only thing to complain about. Structure, content, timelines, sources? Do you intend to expand this A and address the other issues? (Even if not: visit the site given there with tld .org…)

Comment: I read through the original version of the answer as posted in this Meta question. I've seen the newly-posted version and it addresses the concerns I listed, although you're right that it still lacks sources.